# Qt: Alternative to qgraphicsdropshadoweffect

Tags: performance, qt

Is there a way to create shadow like **qgraphicsdropshadoweffect**? Because the **qgraphicsdropshadoweffect** have great impact on PC performance. I tried set boarder radius (stylesheet) but it doesnt look good. Im creating a multiple buttons on a stackwidget and each of it has qgraphicsdropshadoweffect like you guys see on a POS (especially on food). Im using qt 4.7.3.

Edit: Or perhaps a stylesheet that looks like it. But in qt4.7 I cannot use css3. Upgrading to qt 5.0 is not advisable in our situation.

Comment: What kind of app are your creating? Give more details so we can give you a more precise answer.

Comment: Im creating a multiple buttons on a stackwidget and each of it has qgraphicsdropshadoweffect. Im using qt 4.7.3.

Comment: Looking at the source code of the `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` class, you are out of luck, since it is completely CPU dependent. With QML you would be able to achieve the same effect with shaders which in turn would be a lot faster (real time or near real time), but you may need to rework your app/widget.